# Hide comments in ShareLaTeX

Tags: sharelatex

ShareLaTeX now comes with a Word-style track of changes and comments.

Is there a way to hide or resize the comments pane? Its current width is greater than that for the actual LaTeX code, making it almost impossible to work with!

Answer (score 15):

Between the code and the comments panes, there is a thin vertical strip that has an arrow head pointing at the comments pane. This arrow head is centred in this thin strip. Left click it once and the comments pane is reduced to a minimum.

When the comments pane is minimised, the arrow head reverses direction and awaits another left click, which will show the comments pane in full glory once again.

Comment: That's what I want for the answer. Thanks mate

Answer (score 14):

I don't have that feature (I think it's not for free), but I suppose that to hide the panel you have to click on the `Ab Review` button and then switch off the `Track changes`.

[image]

However, you can also ask the customer assistance (`Help > Contact Us` in your project menu), I tried once and they replied very fast.

Comment: Yup! I just had to click AB Review.

Comment: @kilojoules I'm happy to know that it works, as I wrote I could not test it! Thank you for confirming it!